# drupal on development machine slow

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, php, performance, drupal

My drupal site on the development machine loads the pages slow. A page takes between 1500ms and 2500ms. The same site in production on the internet loads pages quick.

Using development tools in drupal I can see that for a simple page with some text and a few custom queries the MySql queries takes about 40ms.

Using YSlow I can see that loading the doc takes more than 2 seconds, all the other components like images, js, css about 500ms.

Disabeling virus scanner makes it another 100ms faster.

I have tried to narrow down the problem but cannot find it. I still have about 1.5 seconds delay I cannot explain. My development environment is:

Windows 7 (64bit)
Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_fcgid/2.3.6
PHP 5.3.8 
MySQL Server 5.5

I would like some advice as where to look for the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I suspect is that youre not running a php opcode cacher.

Is CPU or memory really scarce? What's the hardware in the test machine btw?

Assuming there's no visible spike in cpu, nor scarce memory / heavy paging:

Is phpinfo() loading quickly? (stick `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` into a file called something like `info.php` and fetch it). If yes, your drupal might be trying to resolve the clients address, do a geoip lookup or something else which would explain the 1 second delay, and if other php scripts runs quickly then have fun finding the reason.

Comment: I do not use a php opcode cacher.

Comment: I am also not using a php opcode cacher on my production site (not that I know of). The production site  is on a Linux VPC. I could start using an accelerator but still I cannot explain the difference in load times between development and production.

Comment: I can tell you now that using APC with PHP makes no (or very small) difference. There is still a wait of 1 to 1.5 seconds before the page loads.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. Unfortunately the question is closed for being off topic without motivation.

Comment: So, Michael Hampton sir, please tell me why this question had to be closed? Just stating it is off topic is not very helpful.